# Problem with Internet Explorer layout for a drop down menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, html

I have a drop down menu that I have styled using CSS and a Jquery plugin named: Selectbox. http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/

Everything is working great and looks perfect in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. But for some reason when I click the drop down box in Internet Explorer the drop down floats all the way to the right and not directly beneath the drop down.  I have only been coding 3 months so it could be a really stupid mistake but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="foldersoption">
      <select name="Items" id="Items">
              <option value="option1">My Items</option>
              <option value="option2">Shoes</option>
              <option value="option3">Birthday Ideas</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.foldersoption{
   float: left;
   margin-left: 25px;
}


div.selectbox-wrapper ul li {
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   font-size: 12px;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: left;
   width: 243px;
}

.selectbox {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   font-size: 15px;
   height: 25px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   text-align: left;
   width: 250px;
 }
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Do you have screenshots? I put your code in jsfiddle and it looks fine in IE

Comment: what specific versions of IE are you using?

Comment: @luke - I can give you a screen shot but how do I do that on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @jlego - I am using IE 7

Comment: If you can't post an image maybe provide a link to it?

Comment: Here is a link to the two screenshots.  http://bit.ly/i5uDhV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply zoom and position relative to the foldersoption element, and other elements as needed. For example:

.foldersoption {
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
}

This will force IE to treat it like the other browsers do. IE doesn't handle floating very well - you have to give it some additional configuration & constraints in order for it to work properly.

Edit: Based on the screenshots, IE is complaining about security issues - is there a chance it is blocking certain scripts from loading as well? Try disabling or reducing the security in IE and see if the menu drops.

Edit #2: Actually that plugin you used is old and does not appear to be well tested or maintained. Can I suggest an alternative?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuerySelectBox

You can see an example here: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/

I tested it in IE7 and it seems to work ok. Seems extremely simple to set up, and to change the appearance you only need to change or override the default CSS styles.

Comment: That didn't work.  I tried it on all the classes and nothing was different.

Comment: I am sorry the late response but I wanted to thank you very much for the help.  It worked great.